# What is the difference between Dijkstra and Prim's algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

Can any one tell me the difference between [Dijkstra's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and [Prim's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) algorithms? I know what each of the algorithms do. But they look the same to me. 
Dijkstra's algorithm stores a summation of minimum cost edges whereas Prim's algorithm stores at most one minimum cost edge. Isn't this the same?