# Finding Shortest Route Between 3 or more places (Google Map Route)

Tags: android, google-maps, routes

i'm making app about trip planner where user favorite a few place in a city and i'm suppose to route that place for user.
i need to route each so i can calculate the shortest traveling time possible.

can anyone suggest me how to solve this ?

i know google API have a routing algorithm but that just take place 1 to place 2.
currently i'm thinking about implementing Dijkstra's algorithm to this routing problem.
any suggestion ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need latitude and longitude your places. If you don't have a latitude longitude your places then use Geocoder. Geocoder return latlng from city names. Add this latlng to list.
2. Use distance matrix API for find distance/durations between your places. Send latlng list to distance matrix api. You will get the url for connect to API.
3. Parse JSON objects and get durations/distances. Create matrix with durations/distances.
4. Send your matrix to your algorithm(Dijikstra or prim)

Comment: which better djisktra or prim ? , whats is prim anyway ?

Comment: more information about dijkstra and prim https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794948/what-is-the-difference-between-dijkstra-and-prims-algorithm